# ORM left join query and sum

Tags: django, django-views

I would like to select ALL publishers and related books (if they exist) i.e. a sql left join.  Then I would like to print a report of the items with a book price sum by publisher.  What is the best way to do this?

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Book(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
   price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

Desired result:

```
PublisherA [150]
---Book1 [100]
---Book2 [50]
PublisherB [0]
---<none>
PublisherC [25]
---Book3 [25]
Total [175]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this but try:

**View**

```
from django.db.models import Sum
Publisher.objects.annotate(book_price_sum=Sum('book__price'))
```

**Template**

```
{% for publisher in publishers %}
    Sum of book prices: {{ publisher.book_price_sum }}
    {% for book in publisher.book_set %}
        {{ book.name }}: {{ book.price }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks a million, this worked after changing publisher.book_set to publisher.book_set.all.